# prevent multiple dispatch_queue_create from being created in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

have a view that loads and a serial dispatch queue that is created, loads a ton of stuff in the background and works great.  Problem is when I navigate back and forth to that view a new queue is created again and then I have multiple things doing the exact same work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        //function call to a helper outside the scope of this view 
    });
  }
```

How do I prevent this from happening?

EDIT:
creating my own queue was not necessary so I change my code - same problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a way to achieve what I really desire, prevent my dispatched queued items from running when my view is popped from the navigation stack:

I simple wrap this code around my code that is running in my dispatched queue:

```
-(void) myMethod {
  if (self.view.window) {
   //my code
  }
}
```

This came from watching the Blocks & Multithreading video here by Stanford:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774

great video, helped lot.

Answer (score 3):

Put it in the initialization code or move myQueue to an instance variable and then check for its existence.

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) 
    {
        dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mydomain.myapp.longrunningfunction", NULL);
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
            //function call to a helper outside the scope of this view 
        });
        dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                dispatch_release(myQueue);
            });
        });
    } 
    return self; 
}
```

Or...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    if(!_myQueue)
    {
        _myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mydomain.myapp.longrunningfunction", NULL);
        dispatch_async(_myQueue, ^{
            //function call to a helper outside the scope of this view 
        });
        dispatch_async(_myQueue, ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                dispatch_release(_myQueue);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And if you only want it to run once during a single run of the application you can use [`dispatch_once`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_once)

Comment: You may want to check your release code, looks strange to me but I have not needed to create my own queues yet.

Comment: so I don;t really need to create may own queue

Comment: I usually get away with using a global queue.. `dispatch_queue_t dqueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
  dispatch_async(dqueue, ^(void) { ... });`

Comment: which is what I updated my code to above but I still end up with the same work being done multiple times if they navigate back and forth

Comment: The secret to my answer is the class variable _myQueue, Declare that in the header file then when you do the null check you will know if you have dispatched the queue or not.

Comment: I tried a class variable, and I released my queue on viewDidUnload but things still run in the background even after my view is dealloced and that queue is released.  Also when I navigate away from the view it gets popped from the nav stack and is dealloced so it will always be a null value once it gets pushed back onto it again - right?  queues don't go away until after they are empty.

Comment: That is correct, once popped it will be null so you will need to set another variable if you only want it to load once during an app instance, I will update my answer. Yes that is true once you dispatch the queue it will continue to run even after the view is popped. If that is not desired behavior you need to implement a way to cancel the dispatch.

Comment: why not `dispatch_once`?

Answer (score -1):

If using a storyboard put your initialization in here:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{}
```